# Rating icon l2t-paper-rating is not visible

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to user l2t-paper-rating but its not showing. I've imported the necessary components. I can see it in the shadow dom but it is not visible. Below is the code.

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/l2t-paper-rating/l2t-paper-rating.html">
 .......
........
    <div>
          <l2t-paper-rating rating="4"></l2t-paper-rating>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Chrome.....No errors

Comment: Does this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/vx2rd4Lo/

Comment: yeah...the jsfiddle version works.Even the ones shown in polymer site works.

Comment: Are you using bower to get the packages?

Comment: yes, I'm using bower

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165417/discussion-between-andrew-bone-and-user3310115).